# trying to post request from frontend to backend but getting endpoint 404 error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm sending a post request from the front end to the backend. and I'm getting an error
" Error: Request failed with status code 404 "
" Had Issues POSTing to the backend, endpoint "

I am trying to understand why the post request is not reaching the backend...
this route `router.post('/trade',requireAuth, addTrade)`
the front is react and backend is node.js

This is frontend code - a part of a component that triggers the onAddingNewTrade function

```
            <div className='transaction-new-trade-container input-container-style-dash'>
               <h2>Add new trade</h2>
               <label>Stock symbol</label>
               <input
                  type='text'
                  value={newTrade.symbol}
                  name='symbol'
                  onChange={handleInputChange}
               />

               <label>Shares amount</label>
               <input
                  type='number'
                  value={newTrade.amount === 0 ? '' : newTrade.amount}
                  name='amount'
                  onChange={handleInputChange}
               />

               <label>Entry price</label>
               <input
                  type='number'
                  value={newTrade.entryPrice === 0 ? '' : newTrade.entryPrice}
                  name='entryPrice'
                  onChange={handleInputChange}
               />

               <label>Exit price</label>
               <input
                  type='number'
                  value={newTrade.exitPrice === 0 ? '' : newTrade.exitPrice}
                  name='exitPrice'
                  onChange={handleInputChange}
               />
               <button
                  className='btn-style-3'
                  onClick={() => onAddingNewTrade(newTrade)}
               >
                  Add new trade
               </button>
            </div>
```

This is the onAddingNewTrade function

```
function onAddingNewTrade(newTrade) {
      newTrade.day = utilService.getDate()
      newTrade.pl = tradeService.calculatePL(
         newTrade.symbol,
         newTrade.amount,
         newTrade.entryPrice,
         newTrade.exitPrice
      )
      newTrade.percentage = tradeService.calculatePercentageChange(
         newTrade.entryPrice,
         newTrade.exitPrice
      )
      newTrade.timestamp = Date.now()
      addTrade(newTrade)
   }
```

This is the addTrade function

```
export async function addTrade(trade) {
   try {
      const savedTrade = await tradeService.save(trade)
      console.log('Added Trade', savedTrade)
      store.dispatch(getActionAddTrade(savedTrade))
      return savedTrade // maybe no need for it - consider removing later
   } catch (err) {
      console.log('Cannot add trade', err)
      throw err
   }
}
```

And this is the function from frontend that sending the post request to the backend

```
async function save(trade) {
   var savedTrade
   if (trade._id) {
      savedTrade = await httpService.put(`trade/${trade._id}`, trade) // if trade has Id so update
   } else {
      console.log('sending request to backend', trade)
      savedTrade = await httpService.post('/trade', trade) // if trade does not has id create add new trade
   }
   return savedTrade
}
```

this is trade route from the server file in NODE.JS

```
app.use('/api/trade', tradeRoutes)
```

this is the trade routes file

```
import express from 'express'
import { requireAuth } from '../../middlewares/requireAuth.middleware.mjs'
import { log } from '../../middlewares/logger.middleware.mjs'
import { getTrades, getTradeById, addTrade, updateTrade, removeTrade, addTradeMsg, removeTradeMsg } from './trade.controller.mjs'

const router = express.Router()

// We can add a middleware for the entire router:
// router.use(requireAuth)

router.get('/', log, getTrades)
router.get('/:id', getTradeById)
router.post('/trade',requireAuth, addTrade) // add new trade
router.put('/:id', requireAuth, updateTrade) // update existing trade
router.delete('/:id', requireAuth, removeTrade)
// router.delete('/:id', requireAuth, requireAdmin, removeTrade)

router.post('/:id/msg', requireAuth, addTradeMsg)
router.delete('/:id/msg/:msgId', requireAuth, removeTradeMsg)

export const tradeRoutes = router
```

this is the addTrade function

```
export async function addTrade(req, res) {
  const {loggedinUser} = req
  console.log('from front', req.body)
  try {
    const trade = req.body
    trade.owner = loggedinUser
    const addedTrade = await tradeService.add(trade)
    res.json(addedTrade)
  } catch (err) {
    logger.error('Failed to add trade', err)
    res.status(400).send({ err: 'Failed to add trade' })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have put this in an answer because I couldn't get the back ticks working with the string interpolation syntax in the comments.

You have mounted your router here:

```js
app.use('/api/trade', tradeRoutes)
```

This means anything in your `tradeRoutes` starts implicitly with `/api/trade`. This means:

```js
router.post('/trade',requireAuth, addTrade);
```

Responds to `post` requests from:

```js
/api/trade/trade
```

So you need to `post` to:

```js
savedTrade = await httpService.post('/api/trade/trade', trade)
```

and `put` to:

```js
savedTrade = await httpService.put(`/api/trade/trade/${trade._id}`, trade)
```

**Note**: it may be you are using a framework that internally maps front-end requests to `/api` for you but your tags just suggest just React and Express.

Comment: Hey, I changed the savedTrade like you suggested. but still, I'm getting the same error...

```
Had Issues POSTing to the backend, endpoint: /api/trade/trade, with data:
Request failed with status code 404
```

Comment: So your routing is set-up properly now as per [official docs](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#express-router). Now you need to establish if your `tradeRoutes` is being imported properly but I need to see more of your server.js file. Can you browse in your browser to `/api/trade/` to see if the `router.get('/', log, getTrades)` request responds?

Comment: Well i figure out the issue that was, i changed the endpoint in front to this "trade/" and its working fine. but thanks for trying to help

Comment: @Dor glad you got it working. `trade/` would have been a relative path (no leading /) from where you issued the post request so your front-end must already have been mapped to `/api/trade`. Good luck with your project.